# Postgres SQL - check if parameter is null

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 12.6 in a Java7 application using a hibernate Native query.

I am trying to construct a SQL statement that reads results from a table `journalheader` where it receives one parameter. The parameter values can be **'Matched'** or **'Unmatched'**.

The following solution would be inadequate, because it does not cater for `null` values:

```
select * from journalheader where matched_status = ?1;
```

The table does have some rows with the `matched_status` column of `null`. I would like these rows to be part of the **'Unmatched'** filter.

i.e.

- If the parameter `(?1)` is **'Matched'**, then it will only return rows
  where `matched_status` = 'Matched'.
- If the parameter `(?1)` is **'Unmatched'**, then it will only return rows
  where `matched_status` = 'Unmatched' or null.

**Question**

How do I also check for the `null` values?

**Possible solutions**

I think I may need to add a check on the parameter value, and if it is **'Unmatched'** include `or matched_status is null` in the statement.  I am just not sure how to check the  value of the parameter in the sql statement.

```
select * from journalheader where matched_status = ?1 or <if ?1 equals 'Unmatched'> matched_status is null;
```

Comment: So the "Unmatched filter" would result in passing `null` as `?1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes that's kind of correct. If the parameter is 'Unmatched', it would need to filter on the table where matched_status values are either 'Unmatched' or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword `COALESCE`

```
select * from journalheader where COALESCE(matched_status, 'Unmatched') = ?1;
```

This mean use the value of `matched_status` unless the value is `null`, if the value is `null` then use the value `Unmatched`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `COALESCE`:

```
select * 
from journalheader 
where matched_status = COALESCE(?1,'Unmatched')
```

Or `CASE WHEN`:

```
select * 
from journalheader 
where matched_status =CASE WHEN ?1 is null THEN 'Unmatched' ELSE ?1 END
```